# Rails routes - access controller from mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use controller's action in my routes. The problem is that controller is in an engine. 
Is it possible to do that?

To be more specific:
The application used to have blog functionality as a plugin, but after upgrade to Rails 3.2 that functionality was wrapped into an engine.

It's mounted under '/blog' subdomain. Due to '/blog' prefix urls regarding blog changed and it seems that Google's FeedBurner does not support redirects for blog rss feeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap your collection action in '/blog' scope
just a thought

```
scope '/blog' do
 get 'your_action' => "your_controller#collection_action"
end
```

rake routes yied

```
your_action GET    /blog/your_action(.:format)                                  {:action=>"collection-action", :controller=>"your_controller"}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't want '/blog' prefix in my url. Just domain/your_action(.:format).

Comment: alright and `your_action` would point to some controller in engine ? can you post name of controller and action

Comment: We are using this engine from github:

Comment: We are using this engine from github:https://github.com/avitus/bloggity/blob/master/app/controllers/bloggity/blogs_controller.rb. Action name is feed and notice that controller is wrapped into module Bloggity.

Comment: hmm can you try this `get 'your_feed_action' => "bloggity::blogs#index"`

Comment: You would use a `/` to delimit the engine and the controller: `get 'your_feed_action' => 'bloggity/blogs#index`